# qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found

Tags: plugins, qt5

I am trying to plot something on gnuplot using Mobaxterm for windows subsytem for Linux. I installed QT packages and gnuplot etc and was able to successfully plot what i wanted. After i shut down my PC and reopened to plot the same graph next day i get this error

> ```
>     QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/gnuplot/platforms" ...
> loaded library "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
> qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display via:0
> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this
> ```
>
> problem.
>
> ```
> Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.
> ```

**export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1** then shows

```
> >  Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl") QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at
> "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
> Found metadata in lib
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so,
> metadata= {
>     "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
>     "MetaData": {
>         "Keys": [
>             "offscreen"
>         ]
>     },
>     "archreq": 0,
>     "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
>     "debug": false,
>     "version": 330752 }
> 
> 
> Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
> QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at
> "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so" Found
> metadata in lib
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
> {
>     "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
>     "MetaData": {
>         "Keys": [
>             "vnc"
>         ]
>     },
>     "archreq": 0,
>     "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
>     "debug": false,
>     "version": 330752 }
> 
> 
> Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
> QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at
> "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" Found
> metadata in lib
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
> {
>     "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
>     "MetaData": {
>         "Keys": [
>             "xcb"
>         ]
>     },
>     "archreq": 0,
>     "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
>     "debug": false,
>     "version": 330752 }
> 
> 
> Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
> QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path
> "/usr/lib/gnuplot/platforms" ... loaded library
> "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
> qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display via:0 qt.qpa.plugin: Could
> not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could
> be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
> 
> Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl,
> offscreen, vnc, xcb.
> 
> Could not connect to existing gnuplot_qt. Starting a new one.
> QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path
> "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms" ...
> QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at
> "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so" Found
> metadata in lib
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so,
> metadata= {
>     "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
>     "MetaData": {
>         "Keys": [
>             "eglfs"
>         ]
>     },
>     "archreq": 0,
>     "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
>     "debug": false,
>     "version": 330752 }
> 
> 
> Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
> QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at
> "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so" Found
> metadata in lib
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so,
> metadata= {
>     "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
>     "MetaData": {
>         "Keys": [
>             "linuxfb"
>         ]
>     },
>     "archreq": 0,
>     "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
>     "debug": false,
>     "version": 330752 }
> 
> 
> Got keys from plugin meta data ("linuxfb")
> QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at
> "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so" Found
> metadata in lib
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so,
> metadata= {
>     "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
>     "MetaData": {
>         "Keys": [
>             "minimal"
>         ]
>     },
>     "archreq": 0,
>     "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
>     "debug": false,
>     "version": 330752 }
> 
> 
> Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
> QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at
> "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
> Found metadata in lib
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so,
> metadata= {
>     "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
>     "MetaData": {
>         "Keys": [
>             "minimalegl"
>         ]
>     },
>     "archreq": 0,
>     "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
>     "debug": false,
>     "version": 330752 }
> 
> 
> Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
> QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at
> "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
> Found metadata in lib
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so,
> metadata= {
>     "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
>     "MetaData": {
>         "Keys": [
>             "offscreen"
>         ]
>     },
>     "archreq": 0,
>     "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
>     "debug": false,
>     "version": 330752 }
> 
> 
> Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
> QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at
> "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so" Found
> metadata in lib
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
> {
>     "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
>     "MetaData": {
>         "Keys": [
>             "vnc"
>         ]
>     },
>     "archreq": 0,
>     "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
>     "debug": false,
>     "version": 330752 }
> 
> 
> Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
> QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at
> "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" Found
> metadata in lib
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
> {
>     "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
>     "MetaData": {
>         "Keys": [
>             "xcb"
>         ]
>     },
>     "archreq": 0,
>     "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
>     "debug": false,
>     "version": 330752 }
> 
> 
> Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
> QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path
> "/usr/lib/gnuplot/platforms" ... loaded library
> "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
> qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display via:0 qt.qpa.plugin: Could
> not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could
> be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. 
> Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl,
> offscreen, vnc, xcb.
```

I have tried many things given on this forum but nothing helps.

Can anyone let me know what can i do to get rid of the problem.

thanks